# Trouble installing Grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm using Grails 1.3.7.  I'm having trouble getting Grails to automatically install plugins.  I tried just one, "grails install-plugin quartz 0.4.2", which fails.  How do I adjust my Grails installation so that Grails will be able to locate and install my plugin?  Below is the error I get …

```
$ grails install-plugin quartz 0.4.2
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /Library/grails-1.3.7

Base Directory: /Users/davea/Documents/workspace-sts-2.6.0.SR1/NissanUSA/Technology/Leaf Microsite/eCommerce/eComm
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 1231ms.
Running script /Library/grails-1.3.7/scripts/InstallPlugin.groovy
Environment set to development
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/davea/.grails/1.3.7/plugins
Resolving plugin quartz. Please wait...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    module not found: org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2

==== grailsPlugins: tried

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2!quartz.zip:

  /Users/davea/Documents/workspace-sts-2.6.0.SR1/NissanUSA/Technology/Leaf Microsite/eCommerce/eComm/lib/quartz-0.4.2.zip

==== grailsHome: tried

  /Library/grails-1.3.7/lib/quartz-0.4.2.xml

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2!quartz.zip:

  /Library/grails-1.3.7/lib/quartz-0.4.2.zip

==== grailsHome: tried

  /Library/grails-1.3.7/dist/quartz-0.4.2.xml

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2!quartz.zip:

  /Library/grails-1.3.7/dist/quartz-0.4.2.zip

==== grailsHome: tried

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2!quartz.zip:

  /Library/grails-1.3.7/plugins/grails-quartz-0.4.2.zip

==== localMavenResolver: tried

  /Users/davea/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.pom

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2!quartz.zip:

  /Users/davea/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.zip

==== mavenCentral: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.pom

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2!quartz.zip:

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.zip

==== http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org: tried

  http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.pom

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2!quartz.zip:

  http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.zip

==== http://repository.codehaus.org: tried

  http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.pom

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2!quartz.zip:

  http://repository.codehaus.org/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.zip

==== http://download.java.net/maven/2/: tried

  http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.pom

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2!quartz.zip:

  http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.zip

==== http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/: tried

  http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.pom

  -- artifact org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2!quartz.zip:

  http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/grails/plugins/quartz/0.4.2/quartz-0.4.2.zip

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: org.grails.plugins#quartz;0.4.2: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


Error resolving plugin [name:quartz, group:org.grails.plugins, version:0.4.2].
Plugin not found for name [quartz] and version [0.4.2]
```

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: What happens if you don't specify the version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `grailsCentral()` in the `repositories` section of BuildConfig.groovy. Is this an upgrade from pre-1.3? You need `grailsCentral()` in addition to `grailsPlugins()` and `grailsHome()`.

Comment: Yes, this project was upgraded.  Anyway, you're suggestions worked.  Thanks, -

Answer (score 2):

In `BuildConfig.groovy` make sure you have the following:

```
repositories {

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()  // IT LOOKS LIKE YOU MIGHT BE MISSING THIS ONE
}
```

If this doesn't fix the problem, and you need to connect to the internet through a proxy server, try using the [commands](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/set-proxy.html)

```
grails set-proxy
grails add-proxy
```

to configure the proxy server

Comment: I have all these three in my config, still doesn't download. any other tricks? thx